# Is there a way to have VSCode git commit default to "git commit -a"?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there some way of forcing the commit button in the VSCode UI to always peform "git commit -a"?

A partial solution consists in enabling "smart commit", so that when no changes are staged, it does a "git commit -a".
This almost works, except that it doesn't when new files are created.  One adds the file to git, at which point there is some change staged, and the commit button then performs as a "git commit" rather than "git commit -a".

Is there a way to have always "git commit -a" be the behavior?

And on a related note, is it possible to have VSCode ask whether to add new files to git?

Comment: Why not simply use the command line? Why let a bad Git GUI get in your way?

Comment: git commit -a does not stage new files. From git documentation: `-a, --all` *tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected*

Comment: Exactly topsail.  So when I create new files, I add them.  Then, when I am finished with all the work, I typically do a "git commit -a", which stages both the new files in case they have been further modified, and all the rest of the modified files.  This is what I'd love to do with the UI.

Comment: And matt, yes, that's what I do; I use the good ol predictable command line.  But I am surprised that there's no way to do "git commit -a" simply from the UI, and I was wondering whether I was just missing the obvious trick.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood what you meant by "doesn't work when new files are created". But you can click the stage all changes button. Also there is a menu item to add all. I think the importance of committing only staged changes when there are staged changes is something that must be preserved. How are you adding new files? One by one? I guess I'm not sure of the workflow because I always use the integrated terminal and git command line commands so I guess I'm with matt on this one :) If no one has an answer here you could look for (or open) an issue at VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a button, but VSCode does include the command: `Git: commit (All)`, that you can then associate to a keyboard shortcut.

If not, you need to click on "Stash All Changes", then "Commit":

[image: stash all]

Comment: Oh thanks!  I did not know what that + did! I will accept this answer as I think it answers the question of how one can do it best with the UI.